# Better feature detection for image stitching

Tags: opencv, image-processing, feature-detection

So I'm trying to stitch some intra-oral images as an example. By far I'm using OpenCV-surf with parameters: `hessianThreshold=0`, `extended=True`, `upright=True` and also using `KNN(k=2)` and `cv2.RANSAC` for matching.

Although the features look enough and good by themselves, there is a problem with matching them. I tried to optimize parameters, using sift and brisk, and increasing the number of features as much as possible.
I also mask the teeth and only using features in the mask. Now I'm trying to increase the feature-size for something about 4096 or more but I'm not sure that this is possible using OpenCV.

#### Features and Matching

[image]

#### The result

[image]

Comment: What is the problem matching them? The match result looks typical for any other image pair. Do you mean that the stitching itself is bad? Note that typical stitching is only accurate for planar images, that is, images of a flat plane. Panoramas work out since most things are "far enough" away to not cause artifacts, but any stitching of close-up non-planar scenes (e.g. a mouth) will not stitch together accurately. This is evidenced by your image where the match right around the filling seems quite accurate, but it's off further out on the tooth and way off at the tongue.